# How do I format my HDD to Advanced Format/512E to use 512K blocks with Windows Backup?

Tags: partitioning, windows-backup

I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit. When running Windows Backup onto an external 4TB Touro HDD (2TB partition), I receive the error:

> The last backup did not complete successfully. One of the backup files
>   could not be created. Details: The request could not be performed
>   because of an I/O device error.
>
> Error code: 0x8078002A

From [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/491922/windows-7-backup-to-3tb-seagate-external-drive-got-0x8078002a-error), the cause was given as:

> "The "root cause" is that Windows 7 (and its system tools) does not
>   support a 4K native block size. As a workaround the disk can be
>   formatted with "Advanced Format"/512E to use 512K blocks."

It was suggested I try WD Quick Formatter, but this only works with WD HDDs.

How do I format my HDD to **"Advanced Format"/512E** to use 512K blocks, so I can use Windows Backup with it?

Comment: @Ramhound: that's not the answer I seek. I don't have a WD HDD. It doesn't describe in any way how to format the drive in "Advanced Format"/512E for a non-WD HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound. I've tried using the tool and it does not work. It says "Please connect a WD hard drive and click rescan".

Comment: I did not downvote your question.

Comment: I wonder if you could create a VHD, do the backups to that, and then move the files over. Ugly ugly workaround but it might just work